# Validation for file types not working in laravel 4

Tags: validation, laravel-4

After lots of search and no luck to found the solution.

I am validating a input file in laravel 4.2.*. Using the model validation rules but rules not working for me.

rules i am using in my model.php

```
'reqfile'       => 'mimes:txt,pdf,doc,docx|max:20000'
```

and

```
'reqfile'       => 'mimes:application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,text/plain,application/pdf|max:20000'
```

> After applying these rules the validation errors generated but the errors also appear on the valid file selection.

Here's anybody tells me, where i am wrong to apply the rules.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For this validator rule to work you need to make sure that the value being validated for `reqfile` is an instance of:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File
```

or

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
```

So if you're validating a form, `reqfile` must be a uploaded file. That means its value should come from `Input::file()`. So your validator should look something like this:

```
Validator::make(
    // Value for reqfile
    array('reqfile' => Input::file('reqfile')),
    // Validator rule for reqfile
    array('reqfile' => 'mimes:txt,pdf,doc,docx|max:20000')
);
```

The validation rule will actually try to guess the extension by extracting the mime type and compare that to the extension list passed into the rule. That means that you need to pass file extensions to the rule, not actual mime types, as the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-mimes) clearly states:

> The file under validation must have a MIME type corresponding to one of the listed extensions

Comment: So am I to understand that if you incorporate a file upload element as part of a larger form, and you wish to validate both the uploaded file and fields in the form, you have to use two separate Validator::make() statements?  Specifically, one to validate the fields which uses Input::all() as the data, and a separate one for the uploaded file which uses Input::file('file_fieldname') as the data?  It would be helpful if that were spelled out more explicitly in the Laravel docs...

Comment: @dspitzle No, the file input field is a field like any other as far as the validator is concerned, the only difference being that it holds a file instance instead of a string for example. So you include the validation rule as you would with any other field, there's no need for a separate validator instance. The answer only uses that one field because it was the only one relevant to the question, you can add more values/rules to the arrays.